# where to Add Jquery Validation plugin to Knockout component

Tags: jquery, validation, knockout.js

I wrote a Knockout component, while the ViewModel and the template are in separate files , loaded by RequireJs.

The component is a simple form with few input fields. Now I want to add Jquery Validation Plugins on the form. Which should I put some validation settings? On the main html , or the template html, or ViewModel js?

Index.html

```
<order-ticket params="symbol:symbol,stockname:stockname,state:state,price:price,qty:qty"></order-ticket>

<script type="text/javascript">
ko.components.register('order-ticket', {
    viewModel: { require: 'files/component-order-ticket' },
    template: { require: 'text!files/component-order-ticket.html' }
});

function MyViewModel() {
    this.state = ko.observable('new');
    this.symbol = ko.observable('IBM');
    this.stockname = ko.observable('HSBC');
    this.price = ko.observable(100);
    this.qty = ko.observable(50);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

</script>
```

/files/component-order-ticket.js

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    function OrderTicketViewModel(params) {
        this.symbol = (params && params.symbol || '');
        this.stockname = (params && params.stockname || '');
        this.price = (params && params.price || '');
        this.qty = (params && params.qty || '');
        this.state = (params && params.state || ko.observable('new'));
    }

    OrderTicketViewModel.prototype.emptySymbol = function () {
        this.symbol('');
    };
    OrderTicketViewModel.prototype.changeState = function (state) {
        this.state(state);
    };
    return OrderTicketViewModel;
})
```

/files/component-order-ticket.html

```
<form id="OrderTicketForm" method="post">
    <div>
        Symbol: <input type="text" name="symbol" data-bind="value: symbol"><br />
        Stock: <span data-bind="text: stockname"></span><br />
        Price: <input type="text" name="price" data-bind="value: price"><br />
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" data-bind="value: qty"><br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Validation code:

```
$("#OrderTicketForm").validate({
    rules: {
        symbol: {required:true},
        stock: {
            required: true
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things where if you ask 10 developers you will get 11 different answers. Personally I would put it in the .js file.